# creating a dictionary using two lists (no zip) PYTHON

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dictionary using two lists without the use of zip. can someone help me to finish the code. The function should return an empty dictionary if the lists were empty.

```
key_list=[1,2,3,4]
value_list=['a','b','c','d']

def list_to_dict(key_list,value_list):
    new_dict={}
    if len(key_list)!=0 and len(value_list)!=0:
        for i in range(len(key_list)):
            dict[key_list[i]]=value_list[i]
            return new_dict
```

the output I want is

new_dict={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

Comment: can you provide what output you want ?

Comment: I am a student, we haven't covered that in the course. thanks

Comment: Typo: take out `return new_dict` out of the for-loop

Comment: Is it a prerequisite to use those for loops? I think a `dict` comprehension is more Pythonic

Comment: it is a homework to practise both concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return should go outside the `for` loop scope, also check for the `min` lenght of both lists:

```
def list_to_dict(key_list,value_list):
    new_dict = {}
    if len(key_list) != 0 and len(value_list) != 0:
        for i in range(min(len(key_list), len(value_list))):
            new_dict[key_list[i]] = value_list[i]
    return new_dict
```

Comment: @Myaccount, just `print(list_to_dict(key_list, value)list))` in your script

Answer (score 1):

```
key_list=[1,2,3,4]
value_list=['a','b','c','d']

def list_to_dict(key_list,value_list):
    new_dict={}
    if len(key_list)!=0 and len(value_list)!=0 and len(key_list) == len(value_list):
        for key, index in enumerate(key_list):
            dict[key]=value_list[index]

        return new_dict
```

You had an error in your indentation. Also, both lists need to be the same length to avoid an error, so I added that check. For extra learning, look up enumerate. GL on the rest of your homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
key_list=[1,2,3,4]
value_list=['a','b','c','d']

def list_to_dict(key_list,value_list):
    new_dict={}
    if len(key_list)!=0 and len(value_list)!=0:
        for i in range(len(key_list)):
            new_dict[key_list[i]]=value_list[i]
    return new_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

```
key_list=[1,2,3,4]
value_list=['a','b','c','d']

def list_to_dict(key_list,value_list):
    """using dict comprehension, creating new key-value pair
      for each key present in key list againt the value present in the value list."""

    new_dict={key_list[i]:value_list[i] for i in range(len(key_list))}

    return new_dict

result = list_to_dict(key_list,value_list)
print(result)
```

output

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
key_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
value_list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def list_to_dict(key_list, value_list):
    assert len(key_list) == len(value_list), "Both input lists should have equal length"
    return {key_list[i]: value_list[i] for i in range(len(key_list))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
value_list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_dict={}

def list_dict(key_list,value_list):
    for i in range((len(key_list))-1):
        my_dict[key_list[i]] = value_list[i] #using loop to add one by one
        i=i+1
    return my_dict
```

You can try this for your home work
list_dict(key_list,value_list)